# Windows Authentication for SQL Server using JBDC on a Mac

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, macos, windows-authentication

Is it possible to connect to SQL Server using Windows authentication/integrated security from a Mac? I am using the type 4 JDBC driver provided by Microsoft. The front end (a form application) is coded in Java. Everything works perfectly on Windows but one person in the office uses a Mac.

Is this possible? FYI, I have never used Macs so I am very much the novice with them. I have searched all over the Internet but have not found a solution.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 28):

This information is hard to come by in my experience.  All of my searches turned up wrong (outdated) information since Microsoft changed the rules and added the `authenticationScheme` parameter.  In the interest of helping the next person, here is an example of a connection string that works:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://123.123.123;instance=server1;databaseName=students;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos
```

Also in driver properties set `"Domain"`.  Do not include the domain in any user name setting.

This was tested using Squirrel SQL (Java) with jtds on Mac OSX.  Hopefully the previous sentence has the search terms someone might use who needs to know this information.

Comment: Client: Grails/Groovy 2.0.4, jtds driver MacOSX (under eclipse).  Server: MSSQL 2008, using windows authentication.

Comment: It is worth saying that you need to download jTDS driver (http://jtds.sourceforge.net/index.html), it seems to be the only one with Kerberos integration. I know it is in the connection string but some people might miss it and fail to connect using other drivers.

Comment: Also needed the following in order for things to work completely: ;domain=NT_DOMAIN_NAME

Comment: Where do you set "driver properties"?

Comment: Tested this today using sqljdbc_6.4 driver with squirrel on Mac, worked successfully. I have just added the part of the jdbc url after databaseName, No other settings needed.

Answer (score 4):

[Using Kerberos Integrated Authentication to Connect to SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558122.aspx)

> Beginning in Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server, an application
>   can use the **authenticationScheme** connection property to indicate that
>   it wants to connect to a database using type 4 Kerberos integrated
>   authentication.

---

The [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/index.html) JDBC driver for SQL Server supports Windows authentication simply using the **domain** property as described in the [FAQ](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html).

> **domain**
>
> Specifies the Windows domain to authenticate in. If present and the user name and
>   password are provided, jTDS uses Windows (NTLM)
>   authentication instead of the usual SQL Server authentication (i.e.
>   the user and password provided are the domain user and password). This
>   allows non-Windows clients to log in to servers which are only
>   configured to  accept Windows authentication.
>
> If the domain parameter is present but no user name and password are provided, jTDS uses its native Single-Sign-On library and logs in
>   with the logged Windows user's credentials (for this to work one would
>   obviously need to be on Windows, logged into a domain, and also have
>   the SSO library installed -- consult README.SSO in the distribution on
>   how to do this).

Answer (score 1):

I use jTDS on a mac (10.9).

Using this driver you need to specify the username and password like always, the only difference is that you need to specify domain=WHATEVERTHENTDOMAIN in the connection string (or connection properties if you rather).

So a sample connection string is:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://db_server:1433/DB_NAME;domain=NT_DOMAIN_NAME
```

The jTDS driver then uses NTLM to login to the specified domain with the username and password.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but may be relevant for some people. See this other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835929/connect-to-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-from-a-linux-machine-through-j/37839177?noredirect=1#comment76499441_37839177) that describes how to connect to a SQL Server with Windows Authentication from a Linux machine through JDBC. This will work on mac as well.

Answer (score 0):

jTDS is inferior to Microsoft's JDBC driver (in particular, it cannot figure out the types of parameters in a prepared statement)

Yes, you can authenticate to MS SQL Server using Active Directory authentication, as Active Directory is just Kerberos + LDAP, which are open source and implemented on Mac

Kerberos config `/etc/krb5.conf` :

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = YOUR_REALM.NET

[realms]
YOUR_REALM.NET = {
    kdc = host.your-domain.net
}
```

I needed to use the fully qualified domain name of the KDC, not just the domain name

JDBC Connection String:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://$host;database=$db;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos
```

If `$host` does not have an SPN of `MSSQLSrv/$host`, add `serverSp=$SPN` to the JDBC connection string

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct to say that one driver can determine the data types and another driver can't.  *Any* driver has to look at the implied type based on the arguments passed.  Both jTDS and Microsoft's driver do this.  This is a limitation of the protocol - the database cannot tell the driver which type is correct, because in many queries it can't know what you intend.

In each version, jTDS and Microsoft's driver each have different issues and different advantages. The "best" choice depends on exactly which version of each you look at, and exactly what your needs are.  I've had to switch back and forth as different versions come out - Microsoft breaking in a certain way, then later adding something I wanted.

Answer (score -1):

The following connection string worked for me

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server_name:port_name;useLOBs=false;databaseName=db_name;useNTLMv2=true;domain=domain_name;
```

I'm using [jTDS 1.3.2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/) and [SQuirreL SQL Client](https://sourceforge.net/projects/squirrel-sql/files/1-stable/4.1.0/squirrel-sql-4.1.0-MACOSX-install.jar/download).