# Connect To SQL Server With Windows Authentication From A Linux Machine Through JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, windows-authentication

I want to be able to connect to a SQL Server using jdbc and windows authentication.
I saw some answers on the internet saying i should add the following property to the connection string:

```
integratedSecurity=true;
```

And also add

```
sqljdbc_auth.dll
```

To the java path.

But this, as far as i understand applies only when i'm connecting from a Windows machine.
When i try this on a Linux machine i get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication
```

My question is how do I do it from a Linux machine.

Thanks

Comment: "dll" is a hint that this is probably a windows library. On Linux you'd probably have a ".so" or something other than "dll".

Comment: @Fildor i know, this is why i asked how do i do it from linux.

Comment: @mjn i read this article but it applies to Windows and not Linux as i asked

Comment: I was able to get it to work using jTDS, as explained in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26465897/2144390).

Comment: Thank you @GordThompson my problem is that I can't use jTDS as I also use ssl and the jTDS has a bug that prevents using ssl.

Comment: Have you tried `authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos` of the offical driver? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50561067/1266906

Comment: @TheConstructor this solution applies only to connections from Windows machines as it requires a .dll file. I need to connect from a linux machine.

Comment: @zuckermanori I think that the .dll is only needed for the other authenticationScheme, but I am currently lacking a testing opportunity.

Comment: @TheConstructor I have tested it. It didn't work.

Comment: @zuckermanori Thank you!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Well, eventually I answer my own question:
This is not possible to use Windows authentication from a linux machine using the Microsoft JDBC driver.
This is possible using the jTDS JDBC driver using the following connection string:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://host:port;databaseName=dbname;domain=domainName;useNTLMv2=true;
```

Thank you all for all the comments

Comment: I am trying to implement the same. I am able to connect to SqlServer using jtDs and Windows Authentication from Unix machine but the insert queries are failing. Requesting you to please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39658960/exception-while-using-jtds-for-sqlserver-connectivity) Stack Overflow question

Comment: How are you proving user auth details in this connection string ?
I need to embed everything in the connection url.

Comment: @Pradatta to provide the user and password in the connection string simply add them as key-value pairs at the end of the url. The template url for SQL Server is:
jdbc:jtds:<server_type>://<server>[:<port>][/<database>][;<property>=<value>[;...]]
and so your url would be
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://host:port/database;user=someuser;password=somepass

Comment: @zuckermanori
Thanks. I exactly did that by random guess, after posting this comment, And it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I confirm this works in my case too. For those wondering what the value of their domain is in linux environment, you can obtain it from your login credentials. Example: `CONTOSO.IT\Julio-PC` or `Julio-PC@CONTOSO.IT`, `CONTOSO.IT` is the domain name, and user is `Julio-PC`.

Comment: Hi @zuckermanori - does it workd without ntlmauth.dll, do we need to place any specific file or any specific steps/config to connect from Linux machine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @bharatbhushan no need for ntlmauth.dll. even if you put it it won't help as this is a dll file and you're on linux. no need for any additional file other than the jtds jdbc driver.

Comment: I am getting `Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.` Is there any thing should be done on sqlserver side.

Comment: @YashwanthKambala with the above mentioned configuration?

Comment: It does possible to use `Windows Authentication` on Linux machines provided you have to add your Linux machine under `Domain Controller`. I used this DB URL `jdbc:sqlserver://172.18.44.171:1433;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=javaKerberos;authentication=NotSpecified` more details are here https://stackoverflow.com/q/67190767/1665592

Answer (score 8):

For those who are using DBeaver the way to connect to the SQL Server Database is:

In order to connect to the SQL Server from Linux Debian using DBeaver

**1.- Select SQL Server jTDS driver**

[image]

**2.- Enter the connection information**

[image]

**3.- Go to Driver Properties tab and add the domain, user, password**

[image]

[image]

Just as a note, in some post I found that they needed to change the property USENTLMV2 to TRUE but it worked for me either by putting the USERTLNMV2 in true or false.

A problem that I found was that when I was trying to connect to the database using my user and password the next error was thrown:

*Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.*

[image]

This error was thrown because of my user was about to expire. I tried with another AD user and it could connect.

Comment: Awesome! Worked for me!  I did have to set USERTLNMV2 to true

Comment: Same worked in IntelliJ too, didn't have to set USENTLMv2, only DOMAIN and USER variables.

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR

**It is not possible to use native Windows Authentication for JDBC connections to MSSQL from a JVM running on Linux.**

---

This MSDN article explains the authentiation methods with JDBC on Linux, potential errors, and available options:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2015/01/09/jdbc-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentication/

> ...in the JDBC 4.0 driver, you can use the authenticationScheme
>   connection property to indicate how you want to use Kerberos to
>   connect to SQL.  There are two settings here.
>
> - NativeAuthentication (default) – This uses the sqljdbc_auth.dll and is specific to the Windows platform.  This was the only option
>     prior to the JDBC 4.0 driver.
> - JavaKerberos – Makes use of the Java API’s to invoke kerberos and does not rely on the Windows Platform.  This is java specific and not
>     bound to the underlying operating system, so this can be used on both
>     Windows and Linux platforms.

...

> The following document outlines how to use Kerberos with the JDBC
>   Driver and walks through what is needed to get JavaKerberos working
>   properly.

Using Kerberos Integrated Authentication to Connect to SQL Server
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558122%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: I read this article as well. I still don't understand if i can use the JavaKerberos flag to authenticate with Windows authentication.

Comment: @zuckermanori Kerberos authentication requires a Kerberos server. It is a different standard than native Windows authentication. So you need to check with your system / network administrator first if Kerberos is available for your environment.

Comment: I know it is different, i'm looking for a way to use Windows authentication, not kerberos. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Kerberos can (and does) work with Active Directory via LDAP (usually).

If you can get Kerberos configured and talking with your active directory service, then you should be able to authenticate through it to you MS SQL Server.

I'm in the process of proving if this works (or not).

Comment: @Mishter_Jingles - Never had the time to go into the kerberos solution (Adds a level of complexity that I don't have time to work through right now).

I'll try it again at some point.. Just not now.

Comment: To my knowledge "Windows Authentication" in SQL Server actually effectively means Kerberos authentication. Remember that an AD is one big fat KDC in Kerberos terminology. Active Directory is indeed a very good implementation of a KDC and Kerberos protocol is used natively throughout Windows whenever you request access to some resource, e.g. to a file share, a database, etc. However, most people do not realize that Kerberos is underpinning just about everything in Windows. Most people assume that it is some proprietary auth mechanism, but it really isn't. It is just Kerberos.

Comment: @RossBrigoli - NOPE.  Great for Web Connections but not so good for DB.

I'll have to try the solution below

Comment: @Mishter_Jingles NOPE. Great for Web Connections but not so good for DB. I'll have to try the solution below

Answer (score 4):

I know this is kind of an older topic but in case Google sends people here:

There are two main JDBC drivers for SQL Server. One is from Microsoft and the other from jTDS. jTDS can, amazingly, connect using Windows auth (NTLM) from other platforms, including Linux, as described here: http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#windowsAuth. It can, of course, also use SQL-authenticated logins. SQL-authenticated logins are no harder to use from any OS than any other, so don't forget about those an option.

The version provided by Microsoft is the one from which @mjn provided a quote from the documentation. It is able to connect using Windows authentication by specifying `integratedSecurity=true`, `authenticationScheme=javaKerberos`, and `authentication=NotSpecified`.

It is tricky to get this working even if you don't go out of your way to find more confusion, so always keep in mind which driver you are using - and tell us in these posts so that you can get more specific help.

Comment: getting ` WARN AuthenticationJNI: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll`, <br> ```Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.```

Answer (score 3):

This JDBC URL is validated to work with latest Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[server]:[port];database=[db\;trustServerCertificate=true;integratedSecurity=true;user=[user without domain];password=[pw];authenticationScheme=NTLM;domain=[domain];authentication=NotSpecified
```

Example:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://mysql.myorg.com:1433;database=mydb;trustServerCertificate=true;integratedSecurity=true;user=myuser;password=mypwd;authenticationScheme=NTLM;domain=ad.myorg.com;authentication=NotSpecified
```

Comment: This will automatically trust the server certificate and is not recommended from security perspective.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to connect to a SQL Server 2016 Data Mart and JDBC connection Microsoft JDBC Driver using Windows Authentication using the following script on a Ubuntu Linux Docker Image running on Windows 10.

```
# initializes spark session
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .master('local[*]')\
    .appName('FDM')\
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath","pyspark_jars/*")\
    .config('spark.executor.memory', '4g')\
    .config('spark.driver.memory', '16g')\
    .config('spark.executor.cores', '4')\
    .getOrCreate()

jdbc_url = '''jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER;databaseName=DBNAME;trustServerCertificate=true;integratedSecurity=true;user=USERID;password=PASSWORD;authenticationScheme=NTLM;domain=US;authentication=NotSpecified'''


spark_df = spark.read\
    .format("jdbc")\
    .option("url", jdbc_url)\
    .option("driver","com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")\
    .option("query", 'select top(1000) * from SCHEMA.TABLE')\
    .option("fetchsize", 100000)\
    .load()

spark_df.write.csv('TEST.csv', mode = "overwrite", header=True)
```