# Can SonarQube on Redhat Enterprise Edition use Windows integrated security with a SQLServer database?

Tags: sql-server, sonarqube, redhat

SonarQube documentation https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server implies that a Nix server would not be able to use a SQLServer database since it specifies use of a JDBC security DLL.

Is it possible to use Windows Integrated security for SQlServer on Windows Server with a Redhat Enterprise Linux application server running the SonarQube app server that is connected to the domain AD with SSSD (System Security Services Daemon)?

Another way to put this - does SonarQube Server running on Redhat Enterprise Linux support integrated security with Kerberos for a SQL Server database?

Answer (score 1):

The solution appears to depend on your domain administration and configuration as described in this issue.

[Connect To SQL Server With Windows Authentication From A Linux Machine Through JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835929/connect-to-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-from-a-linux-machine-through-j)

Unfortunately I won't be able to independently verify as we have changed architecture and will not be using Redhat linux for the SonarQube server platform.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it but it seems feasible according to Microsoft documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication

Comment: The article is for running SQLServer on Linux.  A different use case than the question however it may shed some light.  For clarification the question is for SQLServer on Windows Server supporting integrated security for java applications running on RHEL.

Comment: No worries. The proliferation of platform and database options makes use case definition and clarity important.  You helped with that.